# ggplot2 remove outer border around plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I am trying to get rid of the box that ggplot puts around my plot.

Here is some code

```
d = data.frame(x=rep(1:5,2), y=gl(2,5), height=abs(rnorm(10)))

ggplot(d, aes(x, y, height = height, group = y)) + 
   geom_ridgeline(fill="black", colour="white") +
   theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#000000"), plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#000000"))
```

Produces this image:

[image]

I would like to get rid of the small gray line that borders around my plot.

Comment: Thanks. This indeed solves the issue.

Comment: Accept the answer if this is resolved

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the `panel.background = element_rect(..., color = NA)` as an argument in `theme`

Comment: In my case (facet wrapping) you have to set `plot.background = element_rect(color = NA)` in the `theme()`